# (Spring) class path resource exception java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: spring, filenotfoundexception, context-param

I have aded following code to my web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
    classpath:com/neelamhotel/mavenwebproject5/configs/dao-context.xml
</param-value>
```

But I am getting error for the same as

> IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [com/neelamhotel/mavenwebproject5/configs/dao-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/neelamhotel/mavenwebproject5/configs/dao-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Project Structure

[image]

Explorer View

[image]

I know `dao-context.xml` file is there. But then why it is giving an error ?

Updated Explorer view

[image]

Created WAR file view

[image]

Comment: @Jens nope, it is not that. tried it.

Comment: can you add a '/' at the start of the resource? `classpath:/com/neelamhotel/mavenwebproject5/configs/dao-configs.xml` (and try again). Without that, the location is relative to the path from where you're opening the application.

Comment: @Augusto tried not working

Comment: *I know dao-configs.xml file is there*. How do you know? Where do you look for this file?

Comment: @JBNizet I mean I can see it in my source package and that is by default on classpath. So it should be able to find it when I mention `classpath` when passing `param-value`.

Comment: Are you using a Maven or Gradle project? If so, where is that file located in the project? If not, what does the project look like, where is the file located and how is the application built?

Comment: @JBNizet I am using maven and file is located in package 'com.neelamhotel.mavenwebproject5.configs'. i will post a picture of my project structure.

Comment: @JBNizet posted project structure.

Comment: That doesn't tell me where the file is located in the project. Open your **file** explorer and tell me the path of the file from the root of the project. This path should start with `src/`.

Comment: @JBNizet added the explorer view for your convenience.

Comment: There's a dao-context, not a dao-config...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Maven project, `src/main/java` is for **Java** source files. The other files are ignored by Maven.

Resources (i.e. non-Java files) that must be copied and be available in the classpath [must go in `src/main/resources`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_add_resources_to_my_JAR).

Gradle uses the same conventions.

Comment: I have moved `dao-context.xml` to src/main/resources/. And changed the `param-value` as `src/main/resources/dao-context.xml`. But stil getting file not found error

Comment: You don't need to change anything to your spring configuration. What you put in src/main/resources ends up in the classpath. Use the same package structure as what you have now, but inside src/main/resources instead of src/main/java.

Comment: I moved my package inside `resources` and kept the `param-value` to `classpath:com/neelamhotel/mavenwebproject5/configs/dao-context.xml`. But unfortunately still getting file not found error. confusing !!!

Comment: Have you rebuilt and redeployed the webapp? Post an updated explorer view. Check that the file can be found in war file built by Maven, under WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: Everything seems OK. If starting the server from eclipse, try stopping it, cleaning its work directory, and starting it again. Also try dropping the war file in the web server and starting it from outside eclipse.

Comment: Great , it is working now. Thanks for walking me through.